# Browser shows old CSS / Hard refresh/clear cache doesn't work

Tags: html, css, caching, browser-cache

I must have some sort of caching issue. I wrote code to create a download button. The button is meant to exist in 6 different colors, for 6 different topics.

Offline, in Local the CSS rules I wrote, display just fine. The button appear in the 6 different colors according to topic (screenshot 1). However, when I upload and update the CSS file to the live website, it doesn't work. The button appears in just 1 color everywhere and centred (screenshot 2).

It's a wordpress website theme, so I purged the cache. I'm using CMD+SHIFT+R to do a hard refresh, I've tried firefox, chrome and safari - also incognito. Nothing.

The width I chose is 250px and on chrome-developer tools it shows 30%.
Based on that I know that chrome uses an older stylesheet. Even if I change the css classes, chrome refuses to adopt the new ones. Also after a week of waiting - for an automatic refresh, the old CSS is still there.

As I said, I already purged the cache and did hardfresh, not sure what else there is to do. Anyone got an idea?

Screenshot 1 - how it's supposed to look
[image: Screenshot 1 - how it's supposed to look]

Screenshot 2 - how it currently looks
[image: Screenshot 2 - how it currently looks]

The actual CSS
[image: The actual CSS]

CSS that chrome shows
[image: CSS that chrome shows]

Comment: make sure the new CSS-sheet is loaded **after** the old one
can you check if the new styles are even being loaded?

Comment: How do I know which one is loaded first and which one is loaded afterwards? On there server there's only 1 CSS file. I overwrite it once I upload it.

Comment: Probably cached by the server. Can you edit the HTML to change the `?ver=5.8.4` at the end? Since cache often operates on URLs, this will be a "new" file to the cache.

Comment: inspect the element and find out if your CSS from your new file is applied. the question is if the old styling is just overwriting your new styling, or if the new CSS is even being loaded at all. it could be a specifity issue, it could be a priority issue (the CSS-files are being read from top to bottom), a pathing issue and much else.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your different advices. It's fixed now :)

Answer (score 2):

Like ivvija said in the comment. Use a version push on the including URL of your CSS.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yourdomain.com/css/style.css?v=1.0.1a" />`

If you have made changes and it doesn't show up, change the version and it should push the new version. This also works for included javascripts btw. It's wise to use this always, specially when you are done with a development change. Else your visitors could experience the same problem. ✌️